# postfix default smtp route

Tags: postfix

I am using postfix with mailscanner to scan emails. the smtp route(tranport_maps) works fine,

but for domains on default route, i added this

- smtp:[mail.server.net]

but it still gives access denied error, any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the specific error from your logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe mail.server.net does not accept mail relay from the IP address of the postfix server.

Anyway, the exact log entry error would help.